# My custom shortcut for Preview app doesn't work

Tags: macos, preview, shortcut

As you can see, I defined shortcut, restart system, but it is still not visible. Why?

[image]

Comment: `App Shortcuts` allow keyboard combinations to invoke menu items. It doesn't change the appearance of menu items.

Comment: It doesn't work anyway...

Comment: try closing the preferences, then it should ask you to apply your changes. After you have applied these changes, QUIT Preview, then relaunch it. This should apply your changes. I am not completely certain that this will work.

Comment: Confirmed - new shortcuts work on Safari, Finder, for example, but not Preview. idk why. Maybe time to file a bug report?

Comment: Now working in OS X 10.11.1, Preview 8.1 (877)

Comment: This could also have been a mismatch between … and ..., ellipsis vs three dots.

Comment: @MaxRied - You may be right, I might have missed it initially, but after previous mishaps like that I'm usually pretty good at getting my ellipses right these days … vs ...

Answer (score 1):

*Just to give this an answer for future Googlers…*

This appears to have been a bug, fixed in El Capitan 10.11.1 & Preview 8.1 (877)

[image]

Or, as mentioned in comments, the initial tests were mistaking three full-stops for an ellipsis
… instead of …

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add `Tools->` before `Adjust Size...`?

So it'll be "`Tools->Adjust Size...`"

Just like here:

[image: Screenshot of the Keyboard settings showing the Keyboard Shortcuts dialog box with the Preview.app item selection opened to show Tools->Adjust Size...]

It has worked for me since Big Sur...

Comment: Please don't rollback useful edits. Backticks should be used for code formatting (see [Markup of reserved words?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/markup-of-reserved-words)).

Answer (score 0):

Is it only shortcuts that have the 3 dots or ellipsis that are not working in Yosemite Preview or all shortcuts? I'm not able to get any custom app shortcuts to work in Preview using the Keyboard pref pane.  However, as a workaround you can assign those same shortcuts to All Applications and they should work fine in Preview.

Answer (score -1):

Same problem here... sortcuts work everywhere except for Preview.  Also, the shortcut for the selection of content in the side bar ('contents only', 'Bookmarks','Contact Sheet') works even with the shift key pressed (which is not the shortcut displayed).

Assigning the shortcut to All Applications works also in Preview.